# RLC - Understanding Phase Shifts

Tags: basic, passive-networks

[image]

I'm having trouble understanding intuitively phase shift for RLC circuits. For example, I have seen the following:

> In the low-frequency regime, which element is the dominating element (highest gain) in this circuit? For the other two non-dominating passive elements, what are the respective phase shifts?

Now for the first question, I know it is the capacitor, as the other two have gains that are close to zero while the capacitor will have a gain near 1. However, I'm lost for answering the second question? Is there a simple way for me to know what their phase shifts will be? Would that simple way to know the phase shifts of those passive elements help with the high-frequency regime?

Comment: I've never heard of an inductor or capacitor having gain. Impedance yes, gain, no.

Comment: So you're saying that if you were told to find the gain for the inductor/capacitor in the above diagram over any frequency $f$, you would say that there is no gain.

Comment: An inductor and capacitor together at or close to their resonant frequency will certainly magnify either voltage or current but, individually it seems nonesense to talk about a single reactive component having gain even if connected to a resistor. Maybe you mean Q?

Comment: For question 2 phase shift of R is zero and L is 90 degrees. The question did appear to ask for "respective" phase shifts and this can be the only answer.

Comment: @Andyaka (1) What is Q? (2) I don't understand how a capacitor or inductor (or both) can't have respective gains when in a series circuit like the one above, you can define the gain as the element impedance divided by the total impedance of the circuit. (3) How did you get zero and 90 degrees for the phase shifts of the resistor and inductor respectively?

Comment: A theoretical resistor doesn't produce any phase shift by ohms law. A theoretical inductor always (and that is a certain always) never produces any phase shift other than 90 degrees. I think you need to revise your terminolgy and study inductors, resistors and capacitors - phase shift knowledge needs to be fundamantal to answering this question.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense - I didn't know if I was able to simply say that, but now I do. Could you also answer (1) and (2) in my last comment?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21390/discussion-between-arturo-don-juan-and-andy-aka).

Comment: Not really, you need to put your question in order before supplementary question can be expected to be answered.

Comment: Put my current question (this page/post) in order, or the questions raised by (1) and (2)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For 'intuition' of phase shifts in the RLC circuit above, notice that by KCL the current will have the same phase in all components in the loop. E.g.

$$
\theta_{I(t)}=\theta_{I_R(t)}=\theta_{I_L(t)}=\theta_{I_C(t)}
$$

Then remember that:

- The phase of \$V_R\$ equals the phase of \$I_R\$.
- The phase of \$V_C\$ lags the phase of \$I_C\$ by 90\$^\circ\$.
- The phase of \$V_L\$ leads the phase of \$I_L\$ by 90\$^\circ\$.

$$\square$$

For the other question, none of the passive elements have gain > 1, but \$V_C\$ is the dominant term of the voltages at low frequency.

Answer (score 2):

I don't mind talking about gain, we all understand there is no real power gain, but you can trade off signal (voltage or current) here or there in frequency space, for more somewhere else.  (If I look at the Johnson noise from an LRC (R is inductor resistance) it will be strongly peaked at the resonance frequency, with an amplitude Q times bigger than it's non-resonat value.)

As far as the question, at low frequency all the voltage drop is across the cap.
At HF it's all across the inductor.  The current relations follow from the math.

Comment: @ArturoDonJuan  My pleasure, though we are not supposed to add comments, unless they add something to the answer.  My answer implies that power next to a resonance is decreased... I questioned that... but I think it's right.  Of course you want to match the resonance to the signal.